# Mirror shading problem

Tags: mirror

Why this is happends,i am add a miror modifier and move edges to cliping point.If I click on smooth shader i have a black line on miror line..
Plese help
[image: This is flat shading]

[image]

Comment: maybe you have a face inside?

Comment: I don't have :(

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Or some other service, if you prefer. Personally, I avoid that particular site because of [its TOS](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2413/narrowing-down-terms-of-blend-exchange), but of course it's up to you. Or you don't have to provide it anywhere at all; it's just helpful sometimes.